# automapper, Can I auto assign Guid to UserId of my UserDTO?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I want to assign Guid to UserId of my UserDTO if UserId is Null. Is it possible to do this in the CreateMap or creating any formatter?. I am using automapper as an attribute on my Actions in controller.

```
protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>()
                .ForMember(d => d.FullName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just:

```
public class UserDTO
{
    string _userId;
    public string UserId
    {
        get
        {
            if (_userId == null)
                _userId = new Guid().ToString();

            return _userId;
        }
        set { _userId = value; }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is not working and below is not working as well.private Guid _userId;
        public Guid UserId
        {
            get { return _userId ?? (_userId = Guid.NewGuid()); }
            set{ _userId= value; }
        }